# Call every child element of a list

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, responsive

I have different classes of a list item a different `background-image` in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rexy91cu/). How can I hide all the background images? I tried the following code to no avail.

```
ul {
    li. * {
        background-image: none:
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside ---- that HTML is invalid an ul must have just `li`elements as direct childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ul {
    li {
       background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Fixed it for me. Thank you!